# Prevent title page, preface etc from being listed in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, rmarkdown

I am producing a pdf in `rmarkdown` using the `bookdown` package. I have a `.Rmd` file that contains a title page, some acknowledgements etc. I then place my table of contents after these pages, and before the main document. The `toc` is automatically including the preceding pages in the `toc`. How do I prevent this?

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
---

Title page text

\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

## Declarations {-}

## Acknowledgements {-}

## Publications {-}

\newpage


``` {=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}


# General Introduction
````

[image]

I just want the `toc` to start with "General Introduction"

Comment: Just add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` before your preliminary sections.

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly? I have put before "Title page text" and before and  after `pagenumbering{roman}` but still getting the same result

Comment: Hmm, I didn't test with `bookdown`, but now I see it doesn't work. Try `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` before your preliminary sections and \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}} right after them.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `bookdown` requires you to add the `{.unlisted .unnumbered}` classes to the headings: See [§4.18 of the `bookdown` documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html).

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
---
Title page text

\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

## Declarations {.unlisted .unnumbered} 

## Acknowledgements {.unlisted .unnumbered}
  
## Publications {.unlisted .unnumbered}
\newpage


``` {=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}


# General Introduction
````

[image: output of code]

Comment: Sorry, this is still not working for me. I have added my yaml.

Comment: @MarkDavies Indeed, that produces an error, in fact. So `bookdown` is definitely a strange beast.

Comment: @MarkDavies I've updated the solution. This should work now.